# Удалить переменную окружения enviroment PORT=8000 в Windows, не прописанную в Переменных среды

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables, .bashrc

Поднимал локально сервера python, zabbix и т.д.. Прописывали переменные через консоль, команду подсказали, *не запомнил, не записал.*

Далее команда (терминал bash в VScode) `export` выдаёт эти все переменные:

```
declare -x PORT="8000"
declare -x ZABBIX_HOST="http://111.111.111.111/zabbix"
...
```

В переменных среды этих строчек нет
В реестре нет

Эти команды их **не удаляют** и не перезаписывают

```
set PORT=
set PORT ""
setx PORT=""
setx PORT ""
```

Срабатывает команда `unset PORT` ([ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/14893803)), export становится пустым.

Однако, все локальные сервера продолжают пользоваться только портом 8000 и мешать друг-другу жить:

```
Port 8000 is already in use
```

Терминалы перезагружал, винду перезагружал.

Comment: Порт zabbix следует задавать в конфигурационном файле. Тогда бы вся эта чахорда с переменными окружения и не понадобилась бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост, но не предсказуем.
Команда была такая. В `.bashrc` файле прописали

```
. /path/env.file
```

Где точка в начале это сокращение команды `source`

и переменные прописывались при каждой перезагрузке bash терминала.